# most popular character on stdin

Tags: c, ascii

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int ascii[255]; //starts as empty table, will hold all the character occurences
    memset(ascii, 0, sizeof(ascii)); // sets all table values to 0
    int c=0;
    int i=0;
    while (getchar() !=EOF){
        c=getchar();
        ascii[c]=(ascii[c]+1);
    }
    for (i=0;i<255;i++){
        printf("%d;",ascii[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, ive created the above code to check how many times each character occurs in a .txt file, but im getting really erratic behaviour, the numbers that im getting dont reflect the contents of file at all. Could you tell me where is my error?

Comment: trivial to debug....

Comment: i did the ascii[c]++ at first, but i was unsure if its legal construction (im new to this), so i decided to go safe way for now

Comment: @KONAKONA it is legal.

Comment: this pair of lines: 'while (getchar() !=EOF){
        c=getchar();' skips every other input char!  suggest 'while( (c = getchar()) != EOF)

Comment: This should be `int ascii[256]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `getchar()` calls, so you are missing one character in each call, change this

```
while (getchar() != EOF)
```

to

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

and remove the next line

```
c = getchar();
```

Comment: ah i see, its because getchar removes a read character from input, right?

Comment: @KONAKONA yes it is, and you completely discard the first one.

Comment: thanks, works like a charm now. by the way, any idea of what would happen if i were to put a non-ascii character in my file?

Comment: Just read the [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) manual it returns an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`.

Comment: @KONAKONA: `getchar` reads single-byte chars and doesn't interpret them. It also returns a value between 0 and 255 or `EOF`, so your program is safe. The result depends on your encoding.

Comment: @MOehm I wrote a very similar program which was an answer here in Stack Overflow, and it got 3 downvotes, it was accepted by the OP however, and I really fail to see why, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27709884/1983495)